# How to divide grid equally in foundation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, zurb-foundation

I have a footer where in section, I need it to be seperated into 4 parts. 2 up and 2 down. How to do this? I have attached the code. I have attached the image on how i wanted it.

[Click to see Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bflo9.png)

```
<div className="footer">

       <div className="row full-width">

       <div className="large-6 columns">
          <div className="row">

          <div className="small-12 medium-3 large-4 columns">
              <img className="" src="" alt="logo"/>
                            <div className="contact-info">
                                <p className="address">address</p>
                                <p className="email"><a href="mailto: "></a>mail</p>
                                <p className="tele"><a href="tel:">53343</a></p>
                            </div>       
          </div>

          <div className="small-6 medium-3 large-8 columns">

             <div className="row">
                <ul className="list-unstyled  ">
                         <li className=".large-6 columns">
                            <img className="" src="img/transport-icon.jpg" alt="transport-icon"/>
                            <p className="text-uppercase">Fast Shipping</p>
                         </li> 
                          <li className=".large-6 columns">
                            <img className="" src="img/transport-icon.jpg" alt="transport-icon"/>
                            <p className="text-uppercase">Free Return</p>
                         </li> 
                          <li className=".large-6 columns">
                            <img className="" src="img/transport-icon.jpg" alt="transport-icon"/>
                            <p className="text-uppercase">Price Gurantee </p>
                         </li> 
                          <li className=".large-6 columns">
                            <img className="" src="img/transport-icon.jpg" alt="transport-icon"/>
                            <p className="text-uppercase">Online Support</p>
                         </li>    
               </ul>
          </div>
          </div>


          </div>
          </div>

          <div className="large-6 columns">
            <div className="row">

        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you should remove all the `className` properties from your elements and just use `class`. as noted in the Docs, the grid of foundation works with `<div class="">` elements so you're code messes up things a bit.

read more here: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html#basics

and a scheme of the footer would be like:

```
<div class="row footer">
    <div class="small-6 columns">
        <img src="...">
        <p>some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="small-6 columns">...</div>
    <div class="small-6 columns">...</div>
    <div class="small-6 columns">...</div>
</div><!-- end of row -->
```